# Rounding selected columns of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have following data and code to round selected columns of this data.table:

```
mydf = structure(list(vnum1 = c(0.590165705411504, -1.39939534199836, 
0.720226053660755, -0.253198380120377, -0.783366825121657), vnum2 = c(0.706508400384337, 
0.526770398486406, 0.863136084517464, 0.838245498016477, 0.556775856064633
), vch1 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "E"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("vnum1", "vnum2", "vch1"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

```
mydf[,round(.SD,1),]
```

> Error in Math.data.frame(list(vnum1 = c(0.590165705411504,
> -1.39939534199836,  :    non-numeric variable in data frame: vch1

```
cbind(mydf[,3,with=F], mydf[,1:2,with=F][,round(.SD,1),])
```

```
   vch1 vnum1 vnum2
1:    B   0.6   0.7
2:    E  -1.4   0.5
3:    A   0.7   0.9
4:    C  -0.3   0.8
5:    C  -0.8   0.6
```

Is there a method with shorter code?

Comment: `mydf[,round(.SD,1),.SDcols=c("vnum1","vnum2")]` or `mydf[,round(.SD,1),.SDcols=1:2]` ?

Comment: @thelatemail : My real data table has many columns and I will have to enter all their names.

Comment: @rnso - the indexes work too, see edit to the comment.

Comment: If you only need this rounding so that it's printed nicely, you can invest a different strategy, where you define a new print class and the assign it to the specified columns. This would have the advantage of keeping all the details (decimal places) of the numbers in the data. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27013967/3521006) for a similar approach.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you don't mind overwriting your original `mydf`:

```
cols <- names(mydf)[1:2]
mydf[,(cols) := round(.SD,1), .SDcols=cols]
mydf

#   vnum1 vnum2 vch1
#1:   0.6   0.7    B
#2:  -1.4   0.5    E
#3:   0.7   0.9    A
#4:  -0.3   0.8    C
#5:  -0.8   0.6    C
```

Comment: This does not work when I apply it to numerical columns of other data sets using the same variable names, I get `Error... unused argument (.SDcols = cols)`. Can you give an explanation of how these functions are working?

Comment: @user5359531 - are you using a `data.table` and not a standard `data.frame`? This code uses `data.table` specific functions, which you may not have loaded.

Comment: I think that explains it, thanks. Didn't see that when reading the original code.

Comment: Can be shortened to: `mydf[,(cols) := round(.SD,1), .SDcols=1:2]`

Answer (score 85):

Using `dplyr`

If you want to round multiple columns at once:

```
mydf %>% mutate_at(vars(vnum1, vnum2), funs(round(., 1)))
```

Or, if you want to change all columns except "vch1":

```
mydf %>% mutate_at(vars(-vch1), funs(round(., 1)))
```

Or, if you want to change all columns starting with "vnum":

```
mydf %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("vnum")), funs(round(., 1)))
```

Or, if you want to change only numeric columns:

```
mydf %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~round(., 1))
```

You get:

```
  vnum1 vnum2 vch1
1   0.6   0.7    B
2  -1.4   0.5    E
3   0.7   0.9    A
4  -0.3   0.8    C
5  -0.8   0.6    C
```

Comment: Warning: `funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0`

Comment: @PeyM87 `as_tibble(mydf) %>% mutate_at(vars(vnum1, vnum2), funs(round(., 1)))` should work.

Answer (score 34):

`dplyr` works on `data.table` objects!  `dplyr::mutate` (as of dplyr 1.0.0 major update) incorporates flexible specification of columns and functions for modifying the data, using `across`.

To specify all columns that have numeric data:

- `mydf %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(., 1)))`

To specify all columns with names that start with "vnum":

- `mydf %>% mutate(across(starts_with("vnum"), ~round(., 1)))`

It is slightly more wordy than the previous `mutate_if` (which still works but is retired) but it is consistent with other possible specifications and allows for more variations.

---

**Old answer**

You can use `mutate_if` with the added benefit of rounding a column only if it is numeric

`mydf %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 1)`

Comment: ```mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 1))``` leads to the warning message "The `...` argument of `across()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.1.0." whereas ```mutate(across(where(~ is.numeric(.)), ~ round(., 1)))``` works fine.

Comment: thanks! yes, looks like there was ambiguity whether arguments to across should be applied once or per group. edited the answer to reflect latest best practice.

Answer (score 19):

As of `dplyr` 0.8.0, `funs()` is [soft deprecated](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/funs.html). That means that `list(name = ~f(.))` should be used instead of `funs(name = f(.))`:

```
mydf %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(vnum1, vnum2), list(~ round(., 1)))

  vnum1 vnum2 vch1
1   0.6   0.7    B
2  -1.4   0.5    E
3   0.7   0.9    A
4  -0.3   0.8    C
5  -0.8   0.6    C
```

Or written as a simple lambda function:

```
mydf %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(vnum1, vnum2), ~ round(., 1))
```

Then, from `dplyr 1.0.0`, `across()` inside `mutate()` should be used:

```
mydf %>% 
 mutate(across(c(vnum1, vnum2), ~ round(., 1)))
```

The use with select helpers, here selecting variables starting with "vnum":

```
mydf %>% 
 mutate(across(starts_with("vnum"), ~ round(., 1)))
```

Or selecting only numeric variables:

```
mydf %>% 
 mutate(across(where(~ is.numeric(.)), ~ round(., 1)))
```

Answer (score 14):

```
require(data.table)
```

Short and clear solution:

```
mydf[, lapply(.SD, round, 1), vch1]

#   vch1 vnum1 vnum2
#1:    B   0.6   0.7
#2:    E  -1.4   0.5
#3:    A   0.7   0.9
#4:    C  -0.3   0.8
#5:    C  -0.8   0.6
```

Same, but with descriptive details:

```
mydf[, lapply(.SD, round, digits = 1), by = vch1]
```

> If I have many columns, say: (vnum1, vnum2, vch1, vch2, vbin1, vbin2, vbin3) and I want to round only vnum1 and vnum2 ?

In this case you may use `:=` operator and `.SDcols =` argument to specify columns to round:

```
mydf[, 1:2 := lapply(.SD, round, digits = 1), by = vch1]
```

In case you need to round certain columns and exclude other from the output you can use just `.SDcols =` argument to do both at once:

```
mydf[, lapply(.SD, round, digits = 1), by = vch1, .SDcols = "vnum1"]
```

`.SDcols =` can be supplied with column name or it's number,
as a single column by name `.SDcols = "vnum1"` or by number `.SDcols = 1`
as a multi columns by names `.SDcols = c("vnum2", "vnum1")` or by numbers `.SDcols = c(2, 1)`
as a columns range by names `.SDcols = vnum1:vnum2` or by numbers`.SDcols = 1:2`

Comment: If I have many columns, say: (vnum1, vnum2, vch1, vch2, vbin1, vbin2, vbin3) and I want to round only vnum1 and vnum2 ?

Comment: Your solution (using .SDcols = c("vnum2", "vnum1") produces a data.table of only 3 columns: vch1, vnum2, vnum1. It does not produce entire data.table with only vnum1 and vnum2 rounded.

Comment: @rsno Just a second. I will update post with desired result in full compliance to your question.

Comment: @rsno Done. Hope this solution will be helpful.

Comment: I think you don't need "by", following also works: mydf[, 1:2 := lapply(.SD, round, digits = 1), .SDcols = 1:2]

Comment: @rnso You're right, it's not required. I will update accordingly.

Comment: This looks very similar to the answer I had accepted earlier: mydf[,(cols) := round(.SD,1), .SDcols=cols]

Comment: Solution to what you've been asking initially and what I voted up for is - mydf[, lapply(.SD, round, 1), vch1] - it doesn't overwrites mydf so it can't be the same. But in case of columns selection it's very similar.

Answer (score 2):

#### If you want to be able to return a copy, you could use a function

The Function:

```
auto_round_dt<- function(dt, ndigits=3, return_copy=TRUE){
  dt<- data.table::setDT(dt)
  roundme<- names(sapply(dt, class))[which(sapply(dt, class) == "numeric")]
  if(return_copy == TRUE){
    tmp<- data.table::copy(dt)
    out<- tmp[, (roundme):=round(.SD, ndigits), .SDcols=roundme]
    return(out)
  } else{
    return(dt[, (roundme):=round(.SD, ndigits), .SDcols=roundme])
  }
}
```

#### Usage

To return a copy of the table without modifying the original:

```
newdt<- auto_round_dt(dt=mydt, ndigits = 3, return_copy = TRUE)
```

And to modify the object in place:

```
auto_round_dt(dt=mydt, ndigits = 3, return_copy = FALSE)
```

*Note:* You don't have to assign the result from `auto_round_dt` to a new `data.table` if you set `return_copy=` to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest by far:

```
mydf[, vch1, round(mydf[, 1:2], 1)]

#   vnum1 vnum2 vch1
#1:   0.6   0.7    B
#2:  -1.4   0.5    E
#3:   0.7   0.9    A
#4:  -0.3   0.8    C
#5:  -0.8   0.6    C
```

> Interesting method. But what if I have many columns, say: (vnum1, vnum2, vch1, vch2, vbin1, vbin2, vbin3) and I want to round only vnum1 and vnum2 ? Also, some explanation regarding how it is working will be very useful

It's grouping by rounded columns using "by =" of data.table.

Here's is the example based on this method to solve your second level task.

Build-in dataset:

```
>dt <- data.table(names = rownames(datasets::ability.cov$cov), datasets::ability.cov$cov)
>dt
#     names general picture  blocks   maze reading   vocab
#1: general  24.641   5.991  33.520  6.023  20.755  29.701
#2: picture   5.991   6.700  18.137  1.782   4.936   7.204
#3:  blocks  33.520  18.137 149.831 19.424  31.430  50.753
#4:    maze   6.023   1.782  19.424 12.711   4.757   9.075
#5: reading  20.755   4.936  31.430  4.757  52.604  66.762
#6:   vocab  29.701   7.204  50.753  9.075  66.762 135.292
```

Short solution:

```
> dt_round <- dt[, .SD, by = round(dt[, blocks:maze], 1)]
> dt_round
#   blocks maze   names general picture reading   vocab
#1:   33.5  6.0 general  24.641   5.991  20.755  29.701
#2:   18.1  1.8 picture   5.991   6.700   4.936   7.204
#3:  149.8 19.4  blocks  33.520  18.137  31.430  50.753
#4:   19.4 12.7    maze   6.023   1.782   4.757   9.075
#5:   31.4  4.8 reading  20.755   4.936  52.604  66.762
#6:   50.8  9.1   vocab  29.701   7.204  66.762 135.292
```

Initial columns order:

```
> whatever <- setcolorder(dt_round, names(dt))
> whatever
#     names general picture blocks maze reading   vocab
#1: general  24.641   5.991   33.5  6.0  20.755  29.701
#2: picture   5.991   6.700   18.1  1.8   4.936   7.204
#3:  blocks  33.520  18.137  149.8 19.4  31.430  50.753
#4:    maze   6.023   1.782   19.4 12.7   4.757   9.075
#5: reading  20.755   4.936   31.4  4.8  52.604  66.762
#6:   vocab  29.701   7.204   50.8  9.1  66.762 135.292
```

Comment: Interesting method. But what if I have many columns, say: (vnum1, vnum2, vch1, vch2, vbin1, vbin2, vbin3) and I want to round only vnum1 and vnum2 ? Also, some explanation regarding how it is working will be very useful.

Comment: @rnso Well, you're right it's not typical approach to shorten the code for this particular task. It's grouping by rounded columns using "by =" of data.table.
Thank you for your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think from the solutions, the one by Steven Baupre using `dplyr` is the most elegant and applicable selectively across different columns in a dataframe, specially in computational physics.

```
library(dplyr)
gasCriticals %>%
  mutate_each(funs(round(., 0)), depth, pres, temp) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(round(., 2)), pres.pr, temp.pr, temp.r) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(round(., 1)), pres.pc, temp.pc)
```

As you can see, pressure and temperature will be rounded to 0 decimals; pseudo-reduced pressure and temperature to 2 decs; and finally, pseudo-critical pressure and temperature to 1 decimals.

Comment: It's nice to know that you are in favour of one of the suggested methods. But, this is not a proper answer to the question but a judgemental comment to an already existing `dplyr` answer. Please,consider to post this as a comment if you have gained enough reputation and delete this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want/need to avoid specific data.table conventions, you can do this in base R, by converting to a normal data.frame (or if you're starting with a data.frame, then skip the convert step)

vector of column names to convert

`rCols <- c('vnum1', 'vnum2')`

convert to regular data.frame

`mydf1 <- as.data.frame(mydf)`

overwrite only specific columns to be rounded

`mydf1[, rCols] <- apply(mydf1[, rCols], 2, function(x) round(x, 1))`

```
> mydf1
  vnum1 vnum2 vch1
1   0.6   0.7    B
2  -1.4   0.5    E
3   0.7   0.9    A
4  -0.3   0.8    C
5  -0.8   0.6    C
```