# Format numbers with million (M) and billion (B) suffixes

Tags: r, format, currency-formatting

I have large numbers, e.g. currency or dollar:

```
1 6,000,000
2 75,000,400
3 743,450,000
4 340,000
5 4,300,000
```

I want to format them using suffixes, like `M` (million) and `B` (billion):

```
1 6.0 M
2 75.0 M
3 743.5 M
4 0.3 M
5 4.3 M
```

Comment: I guess you could do something like `paste(as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))/1e6, "M")` but I'm not sure how pretty is this...

Comment: Engineering notation is a subset of scientific notation that seeks to have the exponent of 10 be a multiple of 3.  And, someone wrote some R code here for that:  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/engineering-notation-format-td803373.html  -- suggest starting there and changing the print statements.

Comment: @Paul I actually saw that post before I asked this question... but couldn't figure out what was going on...

Comment: If you had a numeric vector, you could have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27013967/3521006) by Spacedman and adapt it to your needs. Advantage would be that the numeric values are not changed, only printed "nicely".

Comment: See also [Convert numbers to SI prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340444/convert-numbers-to-si-prefix) and `sitools`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you begin with this numeric vector `x`,

```
x <- c(6e+06, 75000400, 743450000, 340000, 4300000)
```

you could do the following.

```
paste(format(round(x / 1e6, 1), trim = TRUE), "M")
# [1] "6.0 M"   "75.0 M"  "743.5 M" "0.3 M"   "4.3 M"
```

And if you're not concerned about trailing zeros, just remove the `format()` call.

```
paste(round(x / 1e6, 1), "M")
# [1] "6 M"     "75 M"    "743.5 M" "0.3 M"   "4.3 M"
```

Alternatively, you could assign an S3 class with print method and keep `y` as numeric underneath.  Here I use `paste0()` to make the result a bit more legible.

```
print.million <- function(x, quote = FALSE, ...) {
    x <- paste0(round(x / 1e6, 1), "M")
    NextMethod(x, quote = quote, ...)
}
## assign the 'million' class to 'x'
class(x) <- "million"
x
# [1] 6M     75M    743.5M 0.3M   4.3M  
x[] 
# [1]   6000000  75000400 743450000    340000   4300000
```

You could do the same for billions and trillions as well.  For information on how to put this into a data frame, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162445/how-can-i-maintain-a-vectors-print-method-when-putting-it-into-a-data-frame/28162674#28162674), as you'll need both a `format()` and an `as.data.frame()` method.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. So if my numbers are already numeric I would take out the gsub bit and just keep : round(x/1e6,1) ?

Comment: No problem! I understand that I will have character values as an output. But yeah, I have numerics for the input.

Answer (score 34):

Obviously you first need to get rid of the commas in the formatted numbers, and `gsub("\\,", ...)` is the way to go. This uses `findInterval` to select the appropriate suffix for labeling and determine the denominator for a more compact display. Can be easily extended in either direction if one wanted to go below 1.0 or above 1 trillion:

```
comprss <- function(tx) { 
      div <- findInterval(as.numeric(gsub("\\,", "", tx)), 
         c(0, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12) )  # modify this if negative numbers are possible
      paste(round( as.numeric(gsub("\\,","",tx))/10^(3*(div-1)), 2), 
           c("","K","M","B","T")[div] )}
```

You don't need to remove the `as.numeric` or `gsub` if the input is numeric. It's admittedly superfluous, but would succeed. This is the result with Gregor's example:

```
> comprss (big_x)
 [1] "123 "     "500 "     "999 "     "1.05 K"   "9 K"     
 [6] "49 K"     "105.4 K"  "998 K"    "1.5 M"    "20 M"    
[11] "313.4 M"  "453.12 B"
```

And with the original input (which was probably a factor variable if entered with `read.table`, `read.csv` or created with `data.frame`.)

```
comprss (dat$V2)
[1] "6 M"      "75 M"     "743.45 M" "340 K"    "4.3 M"
```

And of course these can be printed without the quotes using either an explicit `print` command using `quotes=FALSE` or by using `cat`.

Comment: Good solution but you need to add "T" to the suffix array for trillion.  Also, for completeness, you should findInterval on the absolute value to handle negative amounts (but note that it would not be consistent with ISO behavior for rounding negatives).

Comment: Thanks for the perceptive comment. I'm guessing the ISO has nothing to say about the differences in definition of "billion" in the various English -speaking countries. (I do see that Wikipedia's article as of this date claims that the English English have abandoned their earlier position, but I never got that memo.)

Comment: ah sorry I was just talking about handling negative numbers and rounding away from zero (what would happen if you used findInterval on the absolute value of tx) instead of rounding towards positive infinity.

Comment: @42- I was using this function when I encountered some strange behaviour. I've asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46657442/1977587. But linking it back to the post for reference

Comment: After looking at the comments to your question, I suspect your difficulties come from assuming that R supports indexing with zero ... it doesn't. That the reason that items that fall below the first interval boundary will get ignored. If you want  to have a vector of the same length as the first argument you may need to have a `-Inf` boundary and an appropriate value to account for that condition.

Comment: This fails for 0. Try for `c(0.00e+00,2.50e+11,5.00e+11,7.50e+11,1.25e+12)`. The output is `"0 B"   "250 B" "500 B" "750 T" "1.2 B"`. This case occurred when this function was passed in `ggplot` as `labels=comprss`. To address this issue we can initialise the array with 0 i.e., change `c(1, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12)` to `c(0, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12)`. Suggesting this as an edit to improve the answer.

Comment: How can I use this if I want `4.30` instead of `4.3`

Comment: @SNT Didn't see this request until now, but for future users would simply change the 2 at the end of the line starting `paste(` , which is actually in the call to `round`, from a 2 to a 3.

Answer (score 27):

Recent versions (>= v1.0.0 released 2018) of the [`scales`](https://scales.r-lib.org/) package include functionality to print readable labels. If you're using ggplot or tidyverse, `scales` is probably already installed.

In this case, [`label_number`](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_number.html) can be used:

```r
> inp <- c(6000000, 75000400, 743450000, 340000, 4300000)
> scales::label_number(accuracy=0.1, scale_cut=scales::cut_short_scale())(inp)
[1] "6.0M"   "75.0M"  "743.4M" "340.0K" "4.3M"
```

`scales::cut_short_scale()` was introduced only in `scales` v1.2.0 (released 2022) and in earlier versions [`label_number_si`](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_number_si.html) must be used instead (but has since been deprecated):

```r
> inp <- c(6000000, 75000400, 743450000, 340000, 4300000)
> scales::label_number_si(accuracy=0.1)(inp)
[1] "6.0M"   "75.0M"  "743.4M" "340.0K" "4.3M"
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it right in my experience. I don't think a custom function is a right recommendation.

Comment: Note that for currencies, you may want to use `prefix = "$"` or similar.

Comment: `label_number_si()` was deprecated in `scales` 1.2.0. Now use: `scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.1, scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale())(inp)`

Answer (score 8):

Another option, starting with numeric (rather than character) numbers, and works for both millions and billions (and below). You could pass more arguments to `formatC` to customize output, and extend to Trillions if need be.

```
m_b_format = function(x) {
    b.index = x >= 1e9
    m.index = x >= 1e5 & x < 1e9

    output = formatC(x, format = "d", big.mark = ",")
    output[b.index] = paste(formatC(x[b.index] / 1e9, digits = 1, format = "f"), "B")
    output[m.index] = paste(formatC(x[m.index] / 1e6, digits = 1, format = "f"), "M")
    return(output)
}

your_x = c(6e6, 75e6 + 400, 743450000, 340000, 43e6)
> m_b_format(your_x)
[1] "6.0 M"   "75.0 M"  "743.5 M" "0.3 M"   "43.0 M" 

big_x = c(123, 500, 999, 1050, 9000, 49000, 105400, 998000,
          1.5e6, 2e7, 313402182, 453123634432)
> m_b_format(big_x)
 [1] "123"     "500"     "999"    "1,050"   "9,000"    "49,000"
 [7] "0.1 M"   "1.0 M"   "1.5 M"  "20.0 M"  "313.4 M"  "453.1 B"
```

Answer (score 4):

dplyr's `case_when` now offers a more friendly solution to this - e.g:

```
format_bignum = function(n){
  case_when(
    n >= 1e12 ~ paste(round(n/1e12), 'Tn'),
    n >= 1e9 ~ paste(round(n/1e9), 'Bn'),
    n >= 1e6 ~ paste(round(n/1e6), 'M'),
    n >= 1e3 ~ paste(round(n/1e3), 'K'),
    TRUE ~ as.character(n))
}
```

Alternatively you could embed the `case_when` bit inside a `mutate` call.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from other answers and adding to them with the main intent of producing pretty labels for ggplot2 axes. And yes, only positive values (negative will be left as is) since usually I want those suffixes only for positive quantities. Easy to extend to negative numbers.

```
# Format numbers with suffixes K, M, B, T and optional rounding. Vectorized
# Main purpose: pretty formatting axes for plots produced by ggplot2
#
# Usage in ggplot2: scale_x_continuous(labels = suffix_formatter)

suffix_formatter <- function(x, digits = NULL)
{
    intl <- c(1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12);
    suffixes <- c('K', 'M', 'B', 'T');

    i <- findInterval(x, intl);

    result <- character(length(x));

    # Note: for ggplot2 the last label element of x is NA, so we need to handle it
    ind_format <- !is.na(x) & i > 0;

    # Format only the elements that need to be formatted 
    # with suffixes and possible rounding
    result[ind_format] <- paste0(
        formatC(x[ind_format]/intl[i[ind_format]], format = "f", digits = digits)
        ,suffixes[i[ind_format]]
    );
    # And leave the rest with no changes
    result[!ind_format] <- as.character(x[!ind_format]);

    return(invisible(result));
}
```

And example of usage.

```
x <- seq(1:10);
d <- data.frame(x = x, y = 10^x);
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data = d) + geom_line() + scale_y_log10()
```

[without suffix formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtFKd.png)

```
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data = d) + geom_line() + scale_y_log10(labels = suffix_formatter)
```

[with suffix formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LywH9.png)

Comment: Thanks for this! I added handling of negative numbers and posted below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56449202/496209

Answer (score 3):

Since the release of `scales 1.2.0`, [`label_number_si`](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_number_si.html) is now deprecated. You can use `cut_short_scale` instead:

```r
library(scales)
inp <- c(6000000, 75000400, 743450000, 340000, 4300000)

label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale())(inp)
#[1] "6.0M"   "75.0M"  "743.4M" "340K"   "4.3M"
```

Use `space = TRUE` to add space between the number and the unit:

```r
label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale(space = TRUE))(inp)
#[1] "6.0 M"   "75.0 M"  "743.4 M" "340 K"   "4.3 M"
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite @42- function to accommodate % numbers, like this

```
compress <- function(tx) {
  tx <- as.numeric(gsub("\\,", "", tx))
  int <- c(1e-2, 1, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12)
  div <- findInterval(tx, int)
  paste(round( tx/int[div], 2), c("%","", "K","M","B","T")[div] )
}

>tx
 total_reads  total_bases     q20_rate     q30_rate   gc_content 
3.504660e+05 1.051398e+08 6.648160e-01 4.810370e-01 5.111660e-01 
> compress(tx)
[1] "350.47 K" "105.14 M" "66.48 %"  "48.1 %"   "51.12 %"
```

This might be useful to similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Alex Poklonskiy, I needed a formatter for charts. But I needed a version that supports negative numbers as well. This is his adjusted function (I'm not an expert in R programming though):

```
number_format <- function(x, digits = NULL)
{
  intl <- c(1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12)
  suffixes <- c(' K', ' M', ' B', ' T')

  i <- findInterval(x, intl)

  i_neg <- findInterval(-x, intl)

  result <- character(length(x))

  # Note: for ggplot2 the last label element of x is NA, so we need to handle it
  ind_format <- !is.na(x) & i > 0
  neg_format <- !is.na(x) & i_neg > 0

  # Format only the elements that need to be formatted
  # with suffixes and possible rounding
  result[ind_format] <- paste0(
    formatC(x[ind_format] / intl[i[ind_format]], format = "f", digits = digits),
    suffixes[i[ind_format]]
  )
  # Format negative numbers
  result[neg_format] <- paste0(
    formatC(x[neg_format] / intl[i_neg[neg_format]], format = "f", digits = digits),
    suffixes[i_neg[neg_format]]
  )

  # To the rest only apply rounding
  result[!ind_format & !neg_format] <- as.character(
    formatC(x[!ind_format & !neg_format], format = "f", digits = digits)
  )

  return(invisible(result))
}
```

I also adjusted that the `digits` argument is used to round values which do not get a suffix (e.g. `1.23434546`)

Example usage:

```
> print( number_format(c(1.2325353, 500, 132364584563, 5.67e+9, -2.45e+7, -1.2333, -55)) )
[1] "1.2325"     "500.0000"   "132.3646 B" "5.6700 B"   "-24.5000 M" "-1.2333"    "-55.0000"  
> print( number_format(c(1.2325353, 500, 132364584563, 5.67e+9, -2.45e+7, -1.2333, -55), digits = 2) )
[1] "1.23"     "500.00"   "132.36 B" "5.67 B"   "-24.50 M" "-1.23"    "-55.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `scales` package would be to use `unit_format`:

```
inp <- c(6000000, 75000400, 743450000, 340000, 4300000)

scales::unit_format(unit = 'M', scale = 1e-6)(inp)
# "6.0 M"   "75.0 M"  "743.4 M" "0.3 M"   "4.3 M"
```