# Using a vector's print method in a data frame

Tags: r

Consider the following vector `x`

```
x <- c(6e+06, 75000400, 743450000, 340000, 4300000)
```

I wish to print `x` in millions, so I wrote a print method and assign a class to `x`

```
print.million <- function(x, ...) {
    x <- paste0(round(x / 1e6, 1), "M")
    NextMethod(x, quote = FALSE, ...)
}

class(x) <- "million"
```

So now `x` will print how I'd like, with the numeric values also remaining intact.

```
x
# [1] 6M     75M    743.5M 0.3M   4.3M  
unclass(x)
# [1]   6000000  75000400 743450000    340000   4300000
```

Here's the problem I'd like to solve.  When I go to put `x` into a data frame, the print method no longer applies, and the numeric values of `x` are printed normally.

```
(df <- data.frame(x = I(x)))
#           x
# 1     6e+06
# 2  75000400
# 3 743450000
# 4    340000
# 5   4300000
```

The class of the `x` column is still class "million", which is definitely what I want.

```
df$x
# [1] 6M     75M    743.5M 0.3M   4.3M  
class(df$x)
# [1] "AsIs"    "million"
```

**How can I put `x` into a data frame and also maintain its print method?** I've tried all the arguments to `data.frame()` and don't really know where to turn next.

The desired result is the data frame below, where `x` is still class "million", it maintains its underlying numeric values, and also prints in the data frame as it would when it is a vector printed in the console.

```
#        x
# 1     6M
# 2    75M
# 3 743.5M
# 4   0.3M
# 5   4.3M
```

**Note:** This question relates to the second part of [an answer I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159936/how-to-format-large-currency-dollar-values-to-millions-billions-r/28160040#28160040).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need a `format` method and an `as.data.frame` method, like these:

```
x <- c(6e+06, 75000400, 743450000, 340000, 4300000)
class(x) <- 'million'
format.million <- function(x,...)paste0(round(unclass(x) / 1e6, 1), "M")
as.data.frame.million <- base:::as.data.frame.factor
data.frame(x)
```

Comment: it still is a numeric vector.  try `unclass(df$x)` or  `df$x + 10^6`.   (note that i made a correction in the function)

Comment: I'm not calling `df <- data.frame(x = format(x))`.  it's just that print.data.frame` calls the `format` method to determine how to print the data.frame to the console

Comment: if you read `as.data.frame.factor` it's doesn't rely on any of the attributes of factors, and it takes care of everything you need to create a data.frame object from a vector.