# How to change scientific format tick lables to an abreviated form in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot` to make a bar chart. I have already used the `scales` package to change the scientific "2e5" formatting to the full number with commas to separate. I have been unable to change the axis tick labels so that a value of 1,000,000 appears as 1M, and 3,500,000 as 3.5M, etc. How do I do this?

See below for code:

```
# Generate dummy dataframe 
df <- structure(list(month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
), foo = c(2322636.14889234, 8676432.48522654, 207993.984222412, 
3310791.19816422, 7540729.19022292, 7316447.75252789, 2410026.6979076, 
6202864.60500211, 8700672.56037146, 1334956.53280988, 505991.168320179, 
3106733.97500068)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

# create plot
plot.1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, aes(x = month, y = foo)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'darkorchid4', width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Monthly foo measurements", x = "Month", 
       y = "Amount of foo" ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159936/formatting-large-currency-or-dollar-values-to-millions-billions  this will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, aes(x = month, y = foo)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'darkorchid4', width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Monthly foo measurements", x = "Month", 
       y = "Amount of foo" ) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6, sep = ""))
```