# How to hover number formatting to K or M accordingly in R Plotly pie charts and line charts

Tags: r, format, plotly

Hi I am trying to plot a pie chart in R plotly for my shiny app where I want to format hover numbers to K or M but couldn't the correct solution for that
Here is a reproducible code that I am using, any help would be appreciated

```
full_data<-data.frame("Name"=c("Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q3","Q3"),"Values"=c(245645,866556,26440,65046,641131,463265))

desc<-full_data%>%group_by(Name)%>%summarise(values=sum(Values))

fig<-plot_ly(desc,labels=~Name,values=~values,type = "pie",
             insidetextfont = list(color = 'white'),
             marker = list(colors = colors,
                           line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1),hoverformat = ',.0f'))%>%
  layout(title = list(text='<b> Volume(lbs.) </b>',x=0,y=1,titlefont=20),
         font=list(family="Corbel",size=15,color="rgb(33,33,33"),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         legend=list(font=list(size=18)),
         margin = list(pad = 10,t=60))

fig
```

[Here you can see hover number is 1,112,201](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrOC3.png)
what I want this as 1.1M or if the number is less than a million let's say the number is 125,463 then it should be 125.5K  while we hover over the pie chart

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is not clear to me what the desired output it?  could you explain what "format hover numbers to K or M" means?

Comment: Hey @missuse I have added the image for your reference

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159936/format-numbers-with-million-m-and-billion-b-suffixes. The answer `scales::label_number_si` seems particulary easy to use.

Comment: I would have gone with that but the problem for me is in the hovering if numbers need to be displayed other than chart then this would be the perfect solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a custom hover label you can supply a vector to `customdata` argument with the desired formatting and define the appropriate `hovertemplate`.

To get the desired formatting you can use `scales::label_number_si`:

```
library(plotly)

desc <- full_data %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(Values)) %>%
  mutate(lab = scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1)(values))

desc
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Name   values lab  
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1 Q1    1112201 1.1M 
2 Q2      91486 91.5K
3 Q3    1104396 1.1M 

plot_ly(desc,
        customdata = desc$lab, #pass the lab vector
        labels = ~Name,
        values = ~values,
        type = "pie",
        insidetextfont = list(color = 'white'),
        marker = list(colors = colors,
                      line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1),
                      hoverformat = ',.0f'),
        hovertemplate = "%{label} <br> %{customdata} <br>  %{percent}") #define hovertemplate
```

[image]

this works too:

```
plot_ly(desc,
        customdata = ~lab,
        labels = ~Name,
        values = ~values,
        type = "pie",
        insidetextfont = list(color = 'white'),
        marker = list(colors = colors,
                      line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1),
                      hoverformat = ',.0f'),
        hovertemplate = "%{label} <br> %{customdata} <br>  %{percent}")
```

To remove the annoying `trace 0` in the hover add `<extra></extra>`:

```
plot_ly(desc,
        customdata = ~lab,
        labels = ~Name,
        values = ~values,
        type = "pie",
        insidetextfont = list(color = 'white'),
        marker = list(colors = colors,
                      line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1),
                      hoverformat = ',.0f'),
        hovertemplate = "%{label} <br> %{customdata} <br>  %{percent} <extra></extra>")
```

Comment: Thanks, missuse that did my job

Comment: In [python customdata can be an array](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~empet/15366/customdata-for-a-few-plotly-chart-types/#/). However in R a vector is the only possibility. This [workaround](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1548) might come in handy, but I could not make it work.