# How can I convert numbers into abbreviated terms in text?

Tags: r

My data frame is like this

```
location      population        
Canada           38067913       
China           1444216102      
Mexico          130262220
```

And i would need to mutate() the population numbers into a new variable in abbreviated terms as such :

```
location      population        pop_text
Canada           38067913        38.06 milions
China           1444216102       1.44 billions
Mexico          130262220       130.26 millions
```

Comment: What have you tried? A quick search led me to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159936/format-numbers-with-million-m-and-billion-b-suffixes . Does that help?

Comment: You are right, i kept searching for "convert"numbers when i should've been typing "format"numbers. The package "scales" in Tidyverse offers that easy conversion.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to throw together some nested `ifelse()` statements if there are only a handful of alternatives to deal with (as is the case with population size).

```
ifelse(x>=1e12, sprintf("%.2f trillion", x/1e12),
  ifelse(x>=1e9, sprintf("%.2f billion", x/1e9), 
  ifelse(x>=1e6, sprintf("%.2f million", x/1e6), 
  format(x, big.mark=","))))
```

If `df` is your data.frame then yours would be

```
df$pop_text <- 
  ifelse(df$population>=1e12, sprintf("%.2f trillion", df$population/1e12),
    ifelse(df$population>=1e9, sprintf("%.2f billion", df$population/1e9), 
    ifelse(df$population>=1e6, sprintf("%.2f million", df$population/1e6), 
    format(df$population, big.mark=","))))
```

An `ifelse()` evaluates the condition in the first argument (e.g. *is x over 1 trillion?*) and, if true, performs the operation in the second argument and moves to the next value of `x`, and if false, performs the operation in the third argument and moves to the next value of `x`. Placing `ifelse()` calls in the third argument of another means that second `ifelse()` gets evaluated if the first returned a false.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a `switch` based on a comparison with respective powers of 10.

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x, digits=2) {
  u <- mapply(`^`, 10, 0:3*3)^-1 * x
  o <- sum(u > 1) |>
    (\(x) sapply(x, \(i) {
      switch(i, '', 'thousands', 'millions', 'billions')
    }))()
  paste(round(u[u < 1000 & u > 1], digits), o)
})

transform(dat, popText=f(population))
#   location population         popText
# 1  Andorra      77443 77.44 thousands
# 2   Canada   38067913  38.07 millions
# 3    China 1444216102   1.44 billions
# 4   Mexico  130262220 130.26 millions
# 5    Earth 7577130400   7.58 billions
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(location = c("Andorra", "Canada", "China", "Mexico", 
"Earth"), population = c(77443, 38067913, 1444216102, 130262220, 
7577130400)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score -1):

With a little finagling you could hijack how `format.object_size` prints:

```
convert_numbers_into_abbreviated_terms_in_text <- function(x, digits = 1L) {
  key <- setNames(
    c('B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'),
    c('', 'thousands', 'millions', 'billions', 'trillions',
      'quadrillions', 'quintillions', 'sextillions', 'septillions')
  )
  
  sapply(x, function(xx) {
    xx <- format(
      structure(xx, class = 'object_size'), units = 'auto', standard = 'SI',
      digits = digits
    )
    xx <- strsplit(xx, ' ')[[1L]]
    trimws(paste(xx[1L], names(key)[match(xx[2L], key)], collapse = ' '))
  })
}


x <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "location      population        
Canada           38067913       
China           1444216102      
Mexico          130262220")

convert_numbers_into_abbreviated_terms_in_text(x$population)
# [1] "38.1 millions"  "1.4 billions"   "130.3 millions"
convert_numbers_into_abbreviated_terms_in_text(x$population, digits = 2)
# [1] "38.07 millions"  "1.44 billions"   "130.26 millions"


si <- 1000^(0:8)
convert_numbers_into_abbreviated_terms_in_text(si)
# [1] "1"              "1 thousands"    "1 millions"     "1 billions"     "1 trillions"    "1 quadrillions" "1 quintillions"
# [8] "1 sextillions"  "1 septillions"
```